# Implement "add to favorite" in database

Tags: database, security, design-patterns, database-design, relational-database

I have a question regarding database/system design. We have a table `user` with `user_id` and a table `school` with `school_id`. We want to implement a feature so that users can add schools to their "favorites list". I already created a third table that contains the relationship between `user_id` and `school_id`. Now I have the two following questions:

1. When a user removes a school from "my favorites" list, should I delete it or keep it in the database but mark it as "deleted"? I want to keep it but it might leave tons of junk data in the table over time.
2. The front-end design looks similar to like/dislike button on twitter. User can favorite/unfavorite a school with one click. Is there any good way to prevent a bot from constantly hitting the the database by clicking the button?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The answer depends on your application's logic. Both suggestions are ok.
   If you need this data sometime in the future or if you are saving history of user actions then you can mark it as "deleted", else you can delete it immediately.
   (another approach is mark it as deleted temporarily, and have a periodic job that cleans the table)
2. I don't have enough experience with this kind of threat, but a simple solution would be is to limit API calls per second per user